# Behaviour of cin.get() and cin.put()

Tags: c++, buffer, iteration, iostream

The following is a code in C++ which takes a letter as an input and gives it as an output. This continuous until doesn't press `Ctrl+C` i.e `^C`.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    char c;
    do
    {
        c = cin.get();
        cout.put(c);
    }while((c = cin.get())!='\0');
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is the following output:-

```
hello
hlo

hello
el
```

I know that why the first output is coming the way it coming but what about the second? Also, why are there two new lines when I am hitting `enter` key only once. Can I get some help?

Comment: After compiling your code with `g++ -pedantic -Wall -O2` and inputting `hello` twice, I am failing to reproduce this. edit: I have reproduced it by pressing enter twice after the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time, `cin.get()` blocks the thread inside the do-while loop code.
After you have gotten your input, you press enter and you find that 2 linebreaks appear. This is because `cin.get()` inside the do-while loop code has been blocking, and as you press enter, `c` will become `'\n'`. What happens next is `cout.put('\n');`.

At this point, you have the `cin.get()` in the do-while condition blocking your thread, so you end up skipping the `h`, the first `l` and the `o`.

Comment: It means that after the first input, the do-while condition was waiting for an input and when I hit the `return` key, `return` was shown as the output. After I entered the second input, it showed the even digit letters and the newline was due to the return that I has entered after the output of the first input. Is my theory right?

Comment: @kusur I have updated my answer with more correct information. I tested and reproduced the problem and this is what I can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the loop conditiion - you invoke `cin.get()` two times per each loop iteration. The missing characteres are compared to `'\0'` and discarded.

Comment: This is true for the first input as well as for second. But why is the output of second input coming as if the loop has skipped all the odd placed characters? Also, why are there two newlines?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, `cin.get()` is being called twice in the loop, while `cin.put(c)` only once. Since you typed `hello` twice, and one character is skipped each time, the sequence of characters output is: (the characters skipped are in the parentheses): 
`h (e) l (l) o`
`(h) e (l) l (o)`

Comment: This is making sense but why is this happening when I am giving inputs in two different lines ? This should be happening when I give the same input consecutively ( which I am not ) but in that case, it doesn't happen.

Comment: It looks to me like you are pressing enter twice, once to end the input and the other to skip that line. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Two key points should be kept in mind for this problem. These are:-

1. When we press `return` key at the end of the string, it is also
   stored in the buffer and pushed along with all the characters stored
   in it onto the standard output.
2. The output depends on whether there are en even or odd number of
   characters in the string ( including the `return` key )

Say that the string `hello!` is entered and `return` is hit. Then, we again enter `hello!` and hit the `return` key. In both the cases, total number ( in either case ) of characters is `7` and not `6`. In this case the output is:-

```
hello!
hlo

hello!
el!_
```

where `_` denotes the cursor that will be displayed. This is because the `return` key hit after the first string was read by the `cin.get()` command within the `do-while` loop and hence it was printed. After that, the control went to the `do-while` condition and it read the `h` of the second string. This was the reason `h` isn't printed in the second output. After that every even character is displayed. This is the reason that `!` is printed. After that the `return` key is detected by the `do-while` condition which pauses the execution at the `_` position.

Now, if you hit `return` key once, you get `return` two times because once `return` is entered and the other time, it is the output.